# Bayes' rule in application

Tags: statistics, expected-value, bayesian

I am reading the material about variational autoencoders of stanford's cs231n course. In the equations below, I am not sure how they got from the first step to the second using Bayes' rule. From what I know about Bayes' rule, it gives you a formula to compute conditional probabilities. However, this does not look like the same. Can someone give some clarification?

[image]

Comment: $p(b|a)=\frac{p(a|b)p(b)}{p(a)}\Rightarrow p(a)=\frac{p(a|b)p(b)}{p(b|a)}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps for the second step?
\begin{align*}
p_\theta(X|Z)p_\theta(Z) &= p_\theta(Z|X)p_\theta(X)\\
p_\theta(X) &= \frac{p_\theta(X|Z)p_\theta(Z)}{p_\theta(Z|X)}\\
log(p_\theta(X)) &= log\left(\frac{p_\theta(X|Z)p_\theta(Z)}{p_\theta(Z|X)}\right)\\
\mathbb{E}_Z\left[log(p_\theta(X))\right] &= \mathbb{E}_Z\left[log\left(\frac{p_\theta(X|Z)p_\theta(Z)}{p_\theta(Z|X)}\right)\right]
\end{align*}